# value extraction using regular expressions

Tags: c#, regex

I have a text file that contains commands in this format  ex:>> call <<

I want to use a regular expression to extract "call" ..
how could be done?

```
Regex ComandStart = new Regex(">>", RegexOptions.Multiline);
Regex ComandEnd = new Regex("<<", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Answer (score 1):

create the regex:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"ex:>>([a-z]+)<<");
```

then extract if match :

```
var match = regex.Match("ex:>>call<<");
var yourString = match.Groups[1].Value; //yourString = "call" here
```

Comment: Also, you can create named groups: new Regex(@"ex:>>(?<cmd>[a-z]+)<<"); Then: match.Groups["cmd"].Value; Tadaa!

Answer (score -1):

If you're on Windows, you could use Notepad++ with the Regex helper plugin for testing your regex's

This expression works fine for me:

```
/ex:\>\>(.*)\<\</
```

No idea about c# specifically, sorry